# Unity : how to get fixed joint component?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to re link a fixed joint I broke at runtime under a certain condition, but I can't get it to work.

I want to use something like `crachat.GetComponents(FixedJoint).connectedBody = link.GetComponent<Rigidbody>;` or `crachat.GetComponents<FixedJoint>.connectedBody = link.GetComponent<Rigidbody>;` but it does not work

I don't understand what more I could try to do

Comment: it looks like a syntax error, does the code compile?

Comment: no it does not, with "()" it says it is an invalid type, and with "<>" it says it is an invalid method. I think I am missing a using but I haven't been able to find which one

Comment: `crachat.GetComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = link.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();`